# Data binding in go using sqlBoiler

Tags: go, sqlboiler

I am fetching some data from MYSQL database.. Using query data is getting correclty (eg 10 rows)

I want to bind into a list of model for displaying.

But panic error displaying

```
type UserDetails []UserDetail
type UserDetail struct {
    id             string    `json:"id" boil:",bind"`
    ScreenName     string    `json:"screenName" boil:",bind" `
}


func (m *mysqlStore) GetUsersDetails(ctx context.Context) () {
    var userDetails []*models.UserDetail
    err := queries.Raw(`
                SELECT
            user.id,
            user.screen_name
            FROM user
    group by user.id
    `).Bind(ctx, m.db, &userDetails)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(userDetails)
}
```

here using the MYSQLQuery i am getting the correct data. I want to display that in a list of arrary eg:

```
[
 {"id":"1",
   "screenName":"test"},
 {"id":"2",
   "screenName":"test"}
]
```

what is the issue in my go code?

Comment: have you forgotten to json marshal the result ??

Comment: @mh-cbon , I got the issue. No need to include boil in struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer

In this case struct must be

```
type UserDetail struct {
    id             string    `json:"id"`
    ScreenName     string    `json:"screenName"`  
}
```

and

```
 var userDetails []models.UserDetail
```